# Android OpenGL ES Dynamic fog color

Tags: android, opengl-es, fog

I'm using the following method to set fog,

```
public void set_fog(float[] fc){
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_FOG);
        {
          gl.glFogf(GL10.GL_FOG_MODE, GL10.GL_EXP2);
          gl.glFogfv(GL10.GL_FOG_COLOR, fc, 0);
          gl.glFogf(GL10.GL_FOG_DENSITY, fog_density);
          gl.glHint(GL10.GL_FOG_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

          gl.glClearColor(fc[0], fc[1], fc[2], fc[3]);
        }
    }
```

And I call it again to change the fog color,

This is working in the Emulator
But when I test it with Android x86 ausus laptop installed in my laptop it sometimes gives fog correctly and sometimes the whole thing becomes white.

Also I have tested the following method

```
public void set_fogColor(float[] fc){
    gl.glFogfv(GL10.GL_FOG_COLOR, fc, 0);
    gl.glClearColor(fc[0], fc[1], fc[2], fc[3]);
    gl.glFlush();
}
```

Which ended up in the same problem.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with what graphics card you have and whether it will support opengl with Android-x86.

Comment: All the other opengl operations are working.
Dynamic fog some times work but sometimes does not.
Fridiculous, is this the right method to dynamically change the fog color ?